# Javafx how to know which textfield clicked?

Tags: javafx, textfield

in my program there are several textfields..A waiter needs to write the amount of product in a random textfield (textfield should only allow the numbers) and i need to know which textfield is typed and get the number..It can also happen that several textfields are entered..

any ideas ? thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

This method let TextField to finish all processing (copy/paste/undo safe).
Do not requare to make extending class.
And allow you to deside what to do with new text after every change
(to push it to logic, or turn back to previous value, or even to modify it).

```
  // fired by every text property change
textField.textProperty().addListener(
  (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    // Your validation rules, anything you like
      // (! note 1 !) make sure that empty string (newValue.equals("")) 
      //   or initial text is always valid
      //   to prevent inifinity loop
    // do whatever you want with newValue

    // If newValue is not valid for your rules
    ((StringProperty)observable).setValue(oldValue);
      // (! note 2 !) do not bind textProperty (textProperty().bind(someProperty))
      //   to anything in your code.  TextProperty implementation
      //   of StringProperty in TextFieldControl
      //   will throw RuntimeException in this case on setValue(string) call.
      //   Or catch and handle this exception.

    // If you want to change something in text
      // When it is valid for you with some changes that can be automated.
      // For example change it to upper case
    ((StringProperty)observable).setValue(newValue.toUpperCase());
  }
);
```

For your case just put this logic inside, and add this listener on all your text fields. Works perfectly.

```
   if (newValue.equals("")) return; 
   try {
       // ammount entered
     Integer i = Integer.valueOf(newValue); 
       // TextField used
     TextField field = (TextField)((StringProperty)observable).getBean();
     // do what you want with this i and field
   } catch (Exception e) {
     ((StringProperty)observable).setValue(oldValue);
   }
```